# I got empty style tag when I import uncompressed scss or css into js file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I got empty `<style>` in my HTML when I import uncompress `scss` or `css` but css was compressed that it could inject into `<style>` currently

Have any one could help me figure out what is wrong in my webpack config?

Thank a lot!!

In my Js file

```
import './somescss.scss'
```

The module in webpack config file

```
    module: {rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {//js loader},
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                        reloadAll: true,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {outputStyle: 'compressed'},
                }
]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below config work for me

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```